# Apache Parquet Could not read footer: java.io.IOException:

Tags: java, hadoop, io, apache-spark, parquet

I have a SPARK project running on a Cloudera VM. On my project I load the data from a parquet file and then process these data. Everything works fine but The problem is that I need to run this project on a school cluster but there I am having problems while reading the parquet file at this part of code:

```
DataFrame schemaRDF = sqlContext.parquetFile("/var/tmp/graphs/sib200.parquet");
```

I get the following error:

> Could not read footer: java.io.IOException: Could not read footer for
>   file
>   FileStatus{path=file:/var/tmp/graphs/sib200.parquet/_common_metadata;
>   isDirectory=false; length=413; replication=0; blocksize=0;
>   modification_time=0; access_time=0; owner=; group=;
>   permission=rw-rw-rw-; isSymlink=false} at
>   parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readAllFootersInParallel(ParquetFileReader.java:248)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetRelation$$anonfun$28.apply(ParquetRelation.scala:750)

Based on the search online it seems to be a parquet version problem.

What I would like from you is to tell me how can I find the installed parquet version in a computer in order to check if both have the same version. Or in addition, if you know the exact solution for this error would also be perfect!

Comment: Hi Lavdërim, Did you solve it?

Comment: If it was any other format, say `.csv`, you should specify `format="com.databricks.spark.csv"`, while you are reading.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem trying to read a parquet file from S3. In my case the issue was the required libraries were not available for all workers in the cluster.

There are 2 ways to fix that:

- Make sure you added the dependencies on the spark-submit command so it's distributed to the whole cluster
- Add the dependencies on the /jars directory on your SPARK_HOME for each worker in the cluster.

Comment: Similarly, I got this issue when trying to read parquet files from my local machine that I had `synced` from `S3`. Interestingly, after I deleted a `_spark_metadata` folder, which was present in the same directory I was reading from, this issue did not occur for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check your folder permissions. We have seen this error in other environments and it was caused by Spark not having the permission to access the file.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but my fix was a bit different.

This error was thrown because I tried to create a external table pointing to an existing but empty parquet file (no rows, not even a schema).

Answer (score 0):

if you open a parquet file (text editor), at the very bottom you will see something like "parquet-mr" and that could help you know what version/format the file was created from

the method above though simple, the "creator" can be something else like impala or other component that can create parquet files and you can use parquet-tools https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-tools

since it looks like you are using spark to read the parquet file you might be able to work-around it by setting spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown to false. maybe try that first (more info here - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#configuration - change latest to your version of spark).

if that does not work then maybe try if this is an issue with latest version of spark - if it does then you can try to trace history of which commits fixed it and that might give you an insight on possible work-around

or if you know the parquet version you can use (switch) the corresponding branch of parquet-mr (build the parquet-tools for that) and use the tools for that version to test your metadata files (_metadata, _common_metadata) or one of the parquet file - you should be able to reproduce the error and debug from there

Answer (score -1):

Can you try sqlContex.read.load, instead of sqlContext.parquetFile.?

Please refer the below link. 
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#generic-loadsave-functions

Please try and let me know, if that works. If not, we could try other way.